# vote and unvote choices for poll using ajax call

Tags: php, ajax

Here is the URL for my site.

http://domain.com/pollpage.php?id=4&mview=34

After login we can vote for the one poll choice at a time.

In poll page I used ajax call for vote and unvote the poll choices. If the user wants to vote for the choices, they have to just click the vote button. If they want unvote the choice, again click the same voted button. It works fine but sometimes it is not working. Cant unvote the choice after the user vote for the choice. Can anybody know the reason for this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the flags one for vote-up and other for the vote-down. and make a field in database for e.g. like vote. using Ajax it just increment or decrement the values in database respectively.